# JSFiddle react Target Container is not DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsfiddle

In the following  [jsfiddle page](https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/9001/) I am trying to run some React example from one book:

I am new to react and JSFiddle and I do not understand what I have to change to the simple example work. I have read in another post with similar problem that the `<script>` must be the last line inside the `<body>` tag. But I am not importing the React scripts "manually", I am using the JSfiddle resources.

What is the difference in JSFiddle between importing the script files through `<script>` tag and use the Resource options ? and there is one third alternative that is to choose in the combobox the React library where we put js code to.

Comment: Change class to id in `<div class="react-container"></div>`

Comment: You have `document.getElementById('react-container')`, so you need the element to have that id, not that class i.e. change your HTML to `<div id="react-container"></div>`

Comment: Have you tried use id in the div? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `document.getElementById('react-container')` but you are using a class: `<div class="react-container"></div>`

Change your code to:

```
<div id="react-container"></div>
```

For your next question on SO, please post your full question so the SO question is not dependent on JSFiddle

EDIT:
@NightRyder updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/9029/

Comment: why this answer got minus when it is right? 
Updated Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/9029/